Can I declare a dynamic-length array in PineScript?
I need to input a variable number of inputs into a PineScript to draw some price levels. The number of levels may vary day by day, sometimes I need 5, sometimes 7+. I want to declare an array in PineScript that will accept at least 1 array parameter and then have a blank space to enter a 2nd, 3rd, etc. depending on how many are needed for that day.  The input should ignore the last (blank) parameter, signifying the end of the array.  Is something like this possible?

I feel like you are over complicating things in your head. Arrays are dynamic-length by nature.
You just clear the array with array.clear() when it is a new day, and then use array.push() to push values to it. Its size will be automatically adjusted. Then when you need to access the elements of the array, get its length with array.size() and loop over the elements.

You think it's possible, so please answer the question.  I want to ask the user how many items they want in the array for that day, then use that array value to generate an input that asks for a float value X number of times.  PineScript uses dialog boxes to ask for inputs values, but the number of values may change day-to-day, hence the ask about using an array that they populates the correct number of inputs on the dialog box.

Bonus points if you can help me configure my inputs to have at least 1 static input followed by a blank space for the second, which if populated, generates a third, which if left unfilled, goes away, leaving only the array items that have values.
